# Google Plus is using value of 'name' property (from Schema.org Person) as site title

Tags: microdata, title, google-plus, schema.org

I added Schema.org’s `Person` - suddenly Google Plus is using the `name` property as site title! Is this a bug? I was wondering if anyone else ran into the same problem.

This is the code I used

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
<li>Written by: <a rel="author" href="url"> <span itemprop="name">Name</span></a></li>
<li> <a itemprop="email" href="mailto:email@gmail.com">Contact</a></li>
</div>
```

It’s very simple - when I paste a link on Google Plus it will use the `name` value as the site title.

It works correctly on Facebook - just wondering why Google would do that before I run into problems, very annoying. The only alternative would be a vCard.

Comment: Obviously it's extracting the author name and assumes that it is more appropriate to use that as the site title - but it's not more appropriate. Could be a G+ Bug

Answer (score 3):

I suspect it's because that [Person](http://schema.org/Person) schema is the *only* schema used on the page, so Google is assuming that the whole page is supposed to be *about* the person, and that all the other stuff around it is just irrelevant fluff, at least as far as microdata is concerned.

You may want to try marking the whole page as an [Article](http://schema.org/Article) or a [Web Page](http://schema.org/WebPage) or some other [Creative Work](http://schema.org/CreativeWork), and marking the Person item as describing an author of that work (with `itemprop="author"`).

Actually, the [WebPage schema](http://schema.org/WebPage) says that "every web page is implicitly assumed to be declared to be of type WebPage", so just adding `itemprop="author"` to your div might fix it:

```
<div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
<li>Written by: <a rel="author" href="url"> <span itemprop="name">Name</span></a></li>
<li> <a itemprop="email" href="mailto:email@gmail.com">Contact</a></li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are posting on Google+, it *might* help if you have set up the rel="author" (or rel="publisher") reciprocal links between the site and the G+ profile.

But that is just a guess, even though Google's terms now permit data sharing between their properties I don't know that it would extend to helping G+ instantaneously sort out something like that but it can't hurt...Ilmari's comment seemed pretty sound to me.